# Accessing the delegating receiver with by delegation in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, delegation

Given an interface:

```
interface Countable
{
    val count: Int
}
```

And an implementation/factory:

```
fun countable(counter: () -> Int): Countable = object : Countable
{
    override val count: Int
        get() = counter()
}
```

I can implement this using the class `by` delegation feature:

```
class CountableThing : Countable by countable({ 123 })
```

So that this snippet predictably outputs `123`:

```
fun main()
{
    val countableThing = CountableThing()
    println(countableThing.count)
}
```

My question is, in the context of the delegate class, is there any way to get an instance of the delegating receiver?

In other words, can my delegate `Countable` implementation (the anonymous object defined in `fun countable`) see/access the receiver instance of the `CountableThing` class?

I tried this:

```
fun <T> countable(receiver: T, counter: () -> Int): Countable = object : Countable
{
    // ...
}

class CountableThing : Countable by countable<CountableThing>(this, { 123 })
```

But that's not valid, because expectedly:

```
class CountableThing : Countable by countable<CountableThing>(this, { 123 })
                                                             /^^^^
                        'this' is not defined in this context
```

Comment: I always appreciate downvotes as an opportunity to improve, but leave a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it can't, delegate objects are just objects they don't even know if they're going to be used to implement an interface through delegation. However, you can consider using [delegated properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html) which are used to delegate properties setters and getters implementations:

```
class Example {
    var p: String by Delegate()
}

class Delegate {
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): String {
        return "$thisRef, thank you for delegating '${property.name}' to me!"
    }

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: String) {
        println("$value has been assigned to '${property.name}' in $thisRef.")
    }
}
```

then you can use

```
val e = Example()
println(e.p)
```

which prints:

```
Example@33a17727, thank you for delegating ‘p’ to me!
```

As you can see, in your delegate implementation you can use `thisRef` which is a reference to the object whose property is been delegated.